# Debugging with android: "waiting for debugger to attach"

Tags: android, debugging

when i tried to debug my android application with eclipse, the emulator started and shows this message: "Application openconnection is waiting for the debugger to attach",and i got this messages in my console:

```
[2012-04-26 12:12:24 - openconection] ------------------------------
[2012-04-26 12:12:24 - openconection] Android Launch!
[2012-04-26 12:12:24 - openconection] adb is running normally.
[2012-04-26 12:12:24 - openconection] Performing   org.anddev.android.getdatafromtheweb.GetDataFromTheWeb activity launch
[2012-04-26 12:12:24 - openconection] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'emul' is   not available. Launching new emulator.
[2012-04-26 12:12:24 - openconection] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'emul'
[2012-04-26 12:12:33 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Unknown error
[2012-04-26 12:12:33 - openconection] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-04-26 12:12:33 - openconection] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-04-26 12:13:08 - openconection] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-04-26 12:13:08 - openconection] Uploading openconection.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-04-26 12:13:09 - openconection] Installing openconection.apk...
[2012-04-26 12:13:29 - openconection] Success!
[2012-04-26 12:13:29 - openconection] Starting activity  org.anddev.android.getdatafromtheweb.GetDataFromTheWeb on device emulator-5554
[2012-04-26 12:13:30 - openconection] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=org.anddev.android.getdatafromtheweb/.GetDataFromTheWeb }
[2012-04-26 12:13:31 - openconection] Attempting to connect debugger to 'org.anddev.android.getdatafromtheweb' on port 8656
[2012-04-26 12:13:51 - openconection] Launch error: Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection timed out.
```

Is it a problem with port ?
I added this code to my manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"></uses-permission>
```

Edit: i have a default emulator called 'emul' i didn't know why it can be started (by the log )

```
Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'emul' is   not available. Launching new emulator.
```

Comment: You have USB Debugging turned on on your phone and the ADB drivers installed?  Can you use ADB from the command line?

Comment: Try close the emulator and adb, and retry again.

Comment: @Simon i haven't a phone just the emulator and how to turn on USB Debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Close your other applications those maybe use your debug port.
If you use eclipse and other SDK, you maybe need to close others.
Good Luck.

Comment: "maybe need to close others" ? you mean other instance of eclipse? but i work only but one instance.

Comment: Just try eclipse window -> showview -> devices, see that ur emulator is listed. Select it by clicking. Now again try window->showview -> logcat

Comment: i dont know why this log line appear and how to fix it?  "[2012-04-26 12:12:24 - openconection] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'emul' is   not available. Launching new emulator.", why my default emulateur 'emul' is not available?